# CSV Conversion for nested dictionary and re-arrange few aspects

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, pyyaml

I'm having troubles with CSV conversion, I'm not that sure on how to do this (not that familiar with CSV conversion, testing this out as a side project) I have a nested dictionary that I want to create into a CSV:

- I want to set `STRONG_AXE` and `FAST_AXE` under the column `ITEM_ID`
- Make another column called `base` which contains the attack values, `10` and `1`, same with attack speed.
- Crit power has 4 parts to it, the base, scale, spread and max spread, I also want to convert all of those (this is the troublesome part for me)
  into 1 column called `crit-power` with `10.0 0.1 0.1 0.2`.

Let's say I have 'axe.yml' for an rpg:

```
# axe.yml
STRONG_AXE:
  base: iron_axe
  attack-damage: 10
  attack-speed: 1
  crit-power:
      base: 10.0
      scale: 0.1
      spread: 0.1
      maxSpread: 0.2
FAST_AXE:
  base: copper_axe
  attack-damage: 5
  attack-speed: 2
```

Now I open 'axe.yml' as f (file), then I convert it into a dictionary.

```
#writer.py
import csv,yaml 

with open(r'axe.yml') as f:
    dict_data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    print (dict_data)
```

Then the convert dictionary that appears is:

```
{'STRONG_AXE': {'base': 'iron_axe', 'attack-damage': 10, 'attack-speed': 1, 'crit-power': {'base': 10.0, 'scale': 0.1, 'spread': 0.1, 'maxSpread': 0.2}}, 'FAST_AXE': {'base': 'copper_axe', 'attack-damage': 5, 'attack-speed': 2}}
```

So how would the conversion work?
(Dropped coding for a while, sorry for my uh... newbie-ishness)

Comment: [CSV format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) doesn't support the nesting of data. It's tabular with columns of fields and rows of data, with each row having the fields in the same order (and usually all having the same length, although isn't a requirement). To do what you want, you will need to determine some way of mapping (flattening) the nested data into this format.

Comment: ah okay thanks, i'll try

Comment: @martineau undeleted :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to handle the nested data. It creates separate fields for each of the items in the nested dictionary and adds a prefix to each of their names.

```
import csv
import yaml
from pprint import pprint

inp_filepath = 'axe.yml'
outp_filepath = 'axe.csv'

FAST, STRONG = 'FAST_AXE', 'STRONG_AXE'  # Axe type ids.
COMMON_FIELDS = ['base', 'attack-damage', 'attack-speed']
STRONG_AXE_ONLY_FIELDS = ['base', 'scale', 'spread', 'maxSpread']
CRIT_POWER_FIELDS = [('crit-power-' + fieldname) for fieldname in STRONG_AXE_ONLY_FIELDS]
CSV_FILE_FIELDS = ['axe-type'] + COMMON_FIELDS + CRIT_POWER_FIELDS


with open(inp_filepath) as file:
    data = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

with open(outp_filepath, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, CSV_FILE_FIELDS)
    writer.writeheader()

    for axetype, axedata in data.items():
        row = {'axe-type': axetype}

        if axetype == FAST:
            # Add common fields.
            row.update({fieldname: axedata[fieldname] for fieldname in COMMON_FIELDS})

        elif axetype == STRONG:
            # Add common fields.
            row.update({fieldname: axedata[fieldname] for fieldname in COMMON_FIELDS})

            # Then add renamed STRONG only fields.
            crit_power_data = axedata['crit-power']
            row.update({('crit-power-' + fieldname): crit_power_data[fieldname]
                            for fieldname in STRONG_AXE_ONLY_FIELDS})

        else:
            raise RuntimeError(f'unknown axe type "{axetype}" encountered')

#        pprint(row, sort_dicts=False)  # Show row data being written to file.
        writer.writerow(row)

print('Conversion completed')
```

Here's some sample output from the `pprint()` call showing the `row` dictionaries being created that have the prefixed field-name keys in them:

```
{'axe-type': 'STRONG_AXE',
 'base': 'iron_axe',
 'attack-damage': 10,
 'attack-speed': 1,
 'crit-power-base': 10.0,
 'crit-power-scale': 0.1,
 'crit-power-spread': 0.1,
 'crit-power-maxSpread': 0.2}
{'axe-type': 'FAST_AXE',
 'base': 'copper_axe',
 'attack-damage': 5,
 'attack-speed': 2}
```